# Picturebox control in Datarepeater(VisualBasic Power Back) NOT showing its content in Windows form C#.Net

Tags: c#

I have a PictureBox control (PictureBox1) in my data-repeater (VisualBasic Power Back)) in a window form using C#.Net. Below is the code. I tried field type as the bitmap as well as a file location. The image is not showing up while running the form/datarepeater. However, I'm getting the text as in tblTestText is appearing in the data repeater.

C# Code:

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string inputSQL = "SELECT tblTest.tblTestID, tblTest.tblTestText, tblTest.tblTestImage, tblTest.tblTestImageFile FROM tblTest";

        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreDBConn"];
        var con = new OleDbConnection(connStr);


        con.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(inputSQL, connStr);
        adapt.Fill(dt);


        pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", dt, "tblTest.tblTestImage", true));
        //pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", dt, "tblTestImageFile",true));
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dt, "blTestText"));

        dataRepeater1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: How many rows of data do you have in the datatable? It looks like you are trying to display an entire column which contains more than one picture.

Comment: The datatable has many rows and I wish to use datarepeater show the contents . in a form as a continues form. In the above code I tried to bound two columns, one field tblTestImageis of data type OLEObject and another field tblTestImageFile is of data type text. tblTestImageFile  represents a physical file location where the image is stored. I tried to bind both OLEObject as well as physical file location into a pircturebox datarepeater control. I'm not successful on both the cases. Actually, my interest is to use the tblTestImageFile . But for learning purposed I tried both the options.

Comment: You can only bind one image to each picturebox.  Since you have a datatable with multiple rows you have to either have multiple pictureboxes or enumerate through the rows of the table and bind one row image to the picturebox.

Comment: I'm trying to bind one image to the picture box. That is, in a data repeater control, I'm having a picturebox to which I need to bind. In the code snippet in my original post, I tried two fields - one is an OLE object and another is a file path containing an image. Both options are not working. See the line as below is commented. I'm not trying to bind two fields to a single picture box. //pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", dt, "tblTestImageFile",true));

Comment: You are binding to the entire column of the datatable.